# than it is... / than is.../ than

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- Micheal has a tendecy at times of behaving in a way that some of us
>   might see as perhaps more assertive ***than is normally called for***.
>   (Original)
>
> 2- Micheal has a tendecy at times of behaving in a way that some of us
>   might see as perhaps more assertive ***than it is normally called
>   for***.
>
> 3- Micheal has a tendecy at times of behaving in a way that some of us
>   might see as perhaps more assertive ***than normally called for***.

Do all of these sentences above mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Michael is a singular proper noun so we should say Michael *has* a *tendency*.

Option 2 is not correct.  The *it* has nothing to relate to and as it is a pronoun (meaning it is used in place of a noun) it must have something to relate to. If there was something for it to relate to then we could replace 'it' with what it relates to and we would see that we would not need the *is*.  For example:

> 2- Michael has a tendency *when faced with a difficult situation* of behaving in a way that some of us might see as perhaps more assertive than it normally called for.
>
> 2- Michael has a tendency *when faced with a difficult situation* of behaving in a way that some of us might see as perhaps more assertive than *that situation* normally called for.

Option 3 will also be clearly understood.